# Real Analysis (derivative)

Tags: real-analysis

I am completely stuck in this question.
If  $r > 0$  is a rational number, let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $ be defined by $f (x)=x^r\sin (1/x)$ for $x \ne 0$, and $f (0)=0$. Determine those values of $r$ for which $f’(0)$
exists.

Comment: Have you tried writing down the definition of $f'(0)$ and evaluating the limit?

Comment: Homework should be marked as such, and you should at least make some effort.

Comment: please try to write down your efforts and thinking also.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**hint**:-

$f'(x)=rx^{r-1}\sin \frac{1}{x}+x^{r-2} \cos\frac{1}{x}$

now $f'(0)$ exists when $\lim _{x \to 0}x^{r-2} \cos\frac{1}{x}$ exist

Comment: Right derivative is not always the same as right limit of the derivative.

Comment: oh I think I have got it now. now the answer will be r>2. am I right?

Comment: Try r=2 which der. exists , but according to your last expr.it doesn't ..

Comment: should use the definition of derivative..

Answer (score 1):

We look at the behaviour of the difference quotient as $h\to 0$ :

For $r>1$ $$-h^{r-1}\leq \frac{h^r  \sin(1/h)-0}{h} \leq h^{r-1}$$ goes to $ 0$ as $h\to 0 $ .
So, $f'(0)=0$ .

For $ r= 1 $ , the difference quotient oscillates between $-1$ and $1$.

And lastly for $0<r<1$ ,the difference quotient oscillates unboundedly as $h\to 0$ .